# Fluentd change output encapsulation

Tags: arrays, json, logging, output, fluentd

I have a fluentd record

`{"key": "value"}`

but i wish to emit this record encapsulated inside an array (even if only one), like so:

`[{"key": "value"}]`

Is there any configuration i can use to obtain this result?

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently this can be solved with fluentd in a recent version.

My problem is that i'm using an old version and this is not available.

See: https://docs.fluentd.org/output/http#json_array